# Move directory with subdir and files on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, console

I am trying to move a directory with subdirectorys and pictures into another directory. I am using Ubuntu with console.

Which command can I use?

Maybe

**mv /var/www/site1/pictures /var/www/site2/**

Comment: That will work just fine.